# How can i store my select value into a session variable?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to be able to store values in the empty strings, I have a select statement to retrieve these values but I'm not sure how to store them in 'sessionVar' and 'sessionVarAddress'. Here is my code:

```
MySqlCommand select = new MySqlCommand("SELECT personID, address_addressID from person WHERE email='" + emailAddress + "' and password = '" + passwordR + "'", connect); //brings back the person ID if user details are correct

using (MySqlDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader()) //executes the SQL statement
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        string sessionVarAddress = "";
        Session["address_addressId"] = sessionVarAddress;

        string sessionVar = "";                  
        Session["personID"] = sessionVar;

        // other code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *read* the value contained in the MySqlDataReader and assign them to your Session

```
if (reader.Read())
{
    Session["address_addressId"] = reader["address_addressId"].ToString();
    Session["personID"] = reader["personID"].ToString()
}
```

Said that, please do as soon as possible a search on how to use a parameterized query. Your code is really weak, vulnerable to hacking (sql injection) and prone to crash if someone use a single quote in the values passed to the database (parsing)

```
string commandText = @"SELECT personID, address_addressID 
                       from person WHERE email=@email and password = @pwd"; 
MySqlCommand select = new MySqlCommand(commandText, connect); 
select.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailAddress;
select.Parameters.Add("@pwd", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passwordR;
using (MySqlDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader()) 
{
   .....
```